# Error message not showing in new tab in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I have a requirement where on clicking on a user profile it should navigated to new tab in the browser and there an api call is getting triggered which confirms that user is not deleted from the system. If it is deleted then navigate to the home tab of the same new tab and it should show an error on the home tab.

Following is the thing which I have tried:

```
<td>
                  <a [routerLink]="['/user/1/']"
                   target="_blank">{{item.user_id}}</a>
              </td>
```

With this above code a I am able to navigate to new tab and in case user is there then I am able to see his profile.

```
this.service.getProfileNameById(id)
.subscribe((res: any) => {
    //show profile logic
}, exception => {
    this.service.addErrorToToaster(this.error_label, exception.error.message);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
});
```

here if the api throws exception then I want to navigate to home which I am navigating but not able to see the error message on home tab.

I tried debugging it on chrome but as I am navigating to new tab I am not able to debug there in a flow. Is it possible to debug in new tab while navigating as it is opening new tab and there is no way adding debug point within flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality by making use of `gards`specially
[CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) or [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) Guards into which you can send your API call on the basis of its response you can either mark it `resolve` or `reject` on this you can decide where you want to navigate.

Example: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/